# Test Class for batch does not give desired code coverage please help

Tags: apex, unit-test

Class :

```
global class MultiImportBatch implements Database.batchable<sObject>
{
    List<Multi_Import__c> obj = new List<Multi_Import__c>();
    global Database.queryLocator start(Database.batchableContext bc)
    {
        string Query = 'Select ID ,Email__c ,Constituent_ID_Legacy__c ,First_Name__c ,Last_Name__c ,Gender__c , Middle_Name__c ,PhoneNumber__c,Postal_Mail_Opt_In__c ,Salutation__c ,Suffix__c,Accepts_Phone__c,Accepts_Semi_Annual_Mail__c,Address_Line_1__c,Address_Line_2__c,Address_Line_3__c,City__c,Company__c,Country__c,CountryZip__c,State__c, Has_Opted_Out_Of_Email__c,TransactionID__c,Transaction_Name__c,Amount__c from Multi_Import__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.batchableContext bc,List<Multi_Import__c> MultiImport)
    {
        //Create a set of of contact emails for query
        set<String>setContactEmails=new set<String>();
        //iterate the list to get the contact id
        for(Multi_Import__c objMutliImport:MultiImport)
        {
            setContactEmails.add(objMutliImport.Email__c);
        }
        //Map of email and contacts
        map<String,contact> ConMap = new map<String,contact>();
        for(contact objcontact:[select id, Email from contact where email IN : setContactEmails])
        {
            ConMap.put(objcontact.Email,objcontact);
        }
        List <Opportunity> Opp = new List<Opportunity>();
        //List<Multi_Import__c> NewObj = new List<Multi_Import__c>();
        List<Contact> lstcontactToInsert = new List<Contact>();
        //Create a map of Multi_Import__c and Email
        map<String,Multi_Import__c> MapMultiImport = new map<String,Multi_Import__c>();
        For(Multi_Import__c ob : MultiImport)
        {
            if(ConMap.containsKey(ob.Email__c))          
            {            
                Opportunity opt = new Opportunity();
                opt.name = ob.Transaction_Name__c;
                opt.StageName='Closed Won';
                opt.Closedate=system.today();
                opt.npsp__Primary_Contact__c = ConMap.get(ob.Email__c).Id;
                opt.Amount=ob.Amount__C;
                Opp.add(opt);
                //Insert Opp;
            }
            Else
            {
                //Insert new contacts
                Contact insertnew = new Contact(FirstName = ob.First_Name__c, LastName= ob.Last_Name__c, Email=ob.Email__c ,Gender__c=ob.Gender__c , MiddleName=ob.Middle_Name__c, Salutation=ob.Salutation__c, Suffix=ob.Suffix__c, HasOptedOutOfEmail=ob.Has_Opted_Out_Of_Email__c );
                lstcontactToInsert.add(insertnew);
                MapMultiImport.put(insertnew.email,ob);            
            }
        }
        //inserting opportunity for the contacts already existed
        if(Opp.size()>0)
        {
            insert opp;
            System.Debug('The Size of Opp is '+ Opp.size());
        }
        //Creating new contacts
        if(lstcontactToInsert.size()>0)
        {
            insert lstcontactToInsert;
            System.Debug('The Size of List of Contacts To be Inserted are'+lstcontactToInsert.size());
        }
        list<opportunity>lstnewOpps=new List<opportunity>();
        //Creating opportunity for newly created contacts
        for(contact objcontact1:lstcontactToInsert)
        {
            if(objcontact1.id!=NULL)
            {
                //String NewID=insertnew.ID;
                Opportunity opt = new Opportunity();
                if(MapMultiImport.containsKey(objcontact1.email))
                {
                    opt.name = MapMultiImport.get(objcontact1.email).Transaction_Name__c;
                    opt.Amount=MapMultiImport.get(objcontact1.email).Amount__C;
                }
                opt.StageName='Closed Won';
                opt.Closedate=system.today();
                opt.npsp__Primary_Contact__c = objcontact1.id;
                lstnewOpps.add(opt);
            }
        }
        if(lstnewOpps.size()>0)
        {
        insert lstnewOpps;
        }
        System.debug('***********************'+lstnewOpps.size());


    }
    global void finish(Database.batchableContext bc)
    {
        System.Debug('Batch Completed Here');
    }
}
```

And Scheduler :

```
global class Scheduler_class implements Schedulable{

    public static String sched = '*/10 * * * *';  //Every 10 Mins 

    global static String scheduleMe() {
        Scheduler_class SC = new Scheduler_class(); 
        return System.schedule('My batch Job', sched, SC);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        MultiImportBatch b1 = new MultiImportBatch();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b1,50);           
    }
}
```

And test :

```
@isTest(SeeAllData = true)
private class Test_MultiImportBatch 
{
  private static testMethod void Executetest() 
  {
      List<Multi_Import__c> MultiImport = new List<Multi_Import__c>();
        Test.startTest();
         Account acc = new Account(Name='Test');
        insert acc;

        //Insert Contact
        Contact con = new Contact(lastName='test',Email='test@gmail.com');
        insert con;

        //Insert Opportunity
        Date dt = system.TODAY()+4;
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(name='Test',AccountId=acc.id,StageName='Prospecting',CloseDate = dt ,npsp__Primary_Contact__c=con.id);
        insert opp;
        Scheduler_class sh1 = new Scheduler_class();      
        String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
        system.schedule('Test', sch, sh1);
        List<Multi_Import__c> objectList = new List<Multi_Import__c>(); 
        Test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

I tried so many times but doesn't gives me desired output can anyone help .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Akash, you really need to post your test class to get specific feedback here.

Comment: all of the `if (xxx.size() > 0)` statements are completely unnecessary. if the list is empty, the SFDC DML statement does nothing (which is what you want)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to proceed:

1. Examine the query in the `start` method and make sure that the test inserts data that results in records being returned by that query i.e. insert some Multi_Import__c objects.
2. Go though the `execute` method line by line  and make sure that the data inserted by the test causes the paths to be taken e.g. that the Email__c field of Multi_Import__c is set to an email address of a Contact record inserted in the test. Do this for all the lines in the `execute` method. It is not unusual for a test to end up being longer than the code it is testing.
3. Code coverage is an indicator that a test is touching most of the code but the real point of tests is to assert that the code is doing what you expect it to do. So don't focus on coverage but instead focus on checking the results of what the code does using asserts and the coverage will happen as a side-effect.
4. I'm not certain that combining the two asynchronous operations - a `Schedulable` and a `Batchable` - works from a test. If you are getting no coverage, try calling `new Scheduler_class.excute(null)` in place of using `System.schedule`.
5. Only use `(SeeAllData = true)` where absolutely necessary; here the test can setup all the necessary data so it is not necessary.

Comment: #4 is spot on the money here. You need to test your scheduleable and your batchable in different test methods.